# How to create Visual Connectable Web Parts in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I want to create visual connectable web part. The provider web part contains list view part and consumer web is normal User Interface screen which will get Record ID(Row ID) of selected row and get detailed information of that Row ID from List and just display information on User Interface.

I have tried but unable to do.Which interface should we inherit (IWebPartField , IWebPartRow, IWebPartTable , IWebPartParameters ).Please guide for same or if you have any solution please give me.

Please see below screen shot for Provider and Consumer  .

**Provider Web Part :** 
[Provider Web Part Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7omgx.png)

**Consumer Web Part**
[Consumer Web Part Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KshGu.png)

Please guide me to sort out the issue.Any help will be appreciable .

Thanks,

Nitin Jagtap

Comment: Have you looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms469765%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396?